# jinja2 loopcontrols break tag is not encountered

Tags: python-2.7, jinja2

I am having issues with jinja2. I need to enable the loopcontrol extension. I am using jinja2 2.9.5, and have tried with 2.9.4, 2.8.1. I am using python 2.7 However, I get this error:

File "/home/gas2830/apps/egawebsite/app/templates/_macros_paginate.html", line 148, in template
    {% break %}
TemplateSyntaxError: Encountered unknown tag 'break'. Jinja was looking for the following tags: 'elif' or 'else' or 'endif'. The innermost block that needs to be closed is 'if'.

I have the following code:

```
               {% for i in images %}
                    {% if i.product_id == p.id %}
                        <img src="{{ url_for('static', filename='images/uploaded_images/' + i.name ) }}" width="100%", height="100%" >
                        {% break %}
                    {% else %}
                        <p>No images</p>
                    {% endif %}
                {% endfor %}
```

And I have this in my **init**.py:

```
jinja_env = Environment(extensions=['jinja2.ext.loopcontrols'])
app.jinja_env.add_extension('jinja2.ext.loopcontrols')
```

Comment: The error suggests that the loopcontrols extension is not installed. How are you rendering your templates? Are you doing anything out of the ordinary with Jinja2 environments?

Comment: Thanks for answering. I just found a solution for this problem. It turns out that it was not getting installed on time. According to the documentations, once the jinja2 environment is created, no extensions can be added. So I moved the installation to the creation of the environment and it worked!